# Gilbert dipoles vs Ampere dipoles

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, magnetic-monopoles

In Griffiths' textbook there is this problem :

[image]

His solution is that you can't tell whether it's Gilbert or Ampere because in the cavities the field would be the same but I don't understand why is this true for needle cavity :

[image]

Griffiths say the magnetic field  (**B**) is zero because it's approximately the field between two distant point charges, But those point charges are opposite in sign ! (as you can see in the question itself, the surface monopole densities are opposite at the two ends).

**Their fields add together and not cancel each other.**

What am I missing here ? Do you agree with me ?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, Griffiths' argument is incorrect, in fact he is wrong about both models, when applied to finite ferromagnetic cylinder. In both models there will be some residual $\mathbf B$ field in the needle-like cavity due to the fact the cylinder isn't infinitely long. But he is correct on the conclusion, we can't find any difference between fields predicted by the two models.

Griffits is correct that the Gilbertian/Coulombian model of $\mathbf B$ field would predict that inside the magnet in the material medium, the field $\mathbf B$ is antiparallel to $\mathbf M$. This contradicts standard EM theory but cannot be experimentally tested, because we can't measure in-medium. That's why the needle cavity is introduced.

However, in cavity the standard EM theory prediction may (and does) change. In a needle-like cavity aligned with $\mathbf M$, $\mathbf B$ has the same direction as $\mathbf H$, i.e. antiparallel to $\mathbf M$. So measuring only direction of the field in the cavity won't tell us anything; both models predict the same.

In the Gilbertian/Coulombian model, the field is Coulombic integral of "magnetic pole" density. Thus the resulting field is a potential field so it cannot correctly describe the actual field at points where it has non-zero curl, such as at points where magnetization $\mathbf M$ has non-zero curl, such as on magnet's surface. Considering again that it predicts direction of $\mathbf B$ that contradicts standard EM theory, I am not inclined to believe in Gilbertian/Coulombian model of $\mathbf B$ as Griffiths' exercise uses it.

The standard way to use the Gilbertian/Coulombian model (and the reason it survives) is to use it for the field $\mathbf H$. In magnetostatics this field's curl vanishes everywhere
$$
\nabla \times \mathbf H = 0
$$
and due to this and due to Helmholtz' decomposition theorem for $\mathbf H$, this field can be everywhere expressed as the Coulomb integral with generating charge density $\nabla\cdot \mathbf H = - \nabla \cdot \mathbf M$ :

$$
\mathbf H(\mathbf x) = \frac{1}{4\pi}\int_\Omega -\nabla \cdot \mathbf M\frac{\mathbf x' - \mathbf x}{|\mathbf x' - \mathbf x|^3}~d^3\mathbf x'.\tag{C}
$$
In our case of cylinder magnet, the only place where this density is non-zero is on the pole faces, so $\mathbf H$ field can be correctly described by the Gilbertian/Coulombian model (in agreement with standard EM theory) everywhere, including the interior of the magnet and including the cavity.

In the Amperian model, we can use the Biot-Savart formula and there, $\nabla \times \mathbf M$ in the role of current density, to get the $\mathbf H$ field in the cavity:

$$
\mathbf H(\mathbf x) = \int_\Omega \frac{1}{4\pi}\frac{(\mathbf x' - \mathbf x)\times \nabla \times \mathbf M}{|\mathbf x' - \mathbf x|^3}d^3\mathbf x'\tag{BS}.
$$

However, the fact that both formula (C) and (BS) can be  derived in general from standard EM theory suggests that these formulas are equivalent in the cavity, i.e. they give the same field $\mathbf H$ in cavity.

We know the field $\mathbf H$ is anti-parallel to $\mathbf M$ in magnet's material medium and in the needle cavity as well. In the needle cavity, $\mathbf B$ field has the same direction as $\mathbf H$.

How can Biot-Savart law result in such a strange direction of field $\mathbf B$ in cavity, which is opposite to its direction in the medium just outside the cavity?

By making the cavity, we introduce additional surface with surface current with opposite direction of flow than the outer surface has. Because this inner surface is closer to the point inside the cavity, it has greater impact on the $\mathbf B$ field there. So direction of the $\mathbf B$ field in the cavity is determined by direction of bound current on the inner surface, not by current on the outer surface. That's why the direction of $\mathbf B$ in the cavity is reversed. And why such experiment won't be able to distinguish between the two models: when properly applied, they are mathematically equivalent, they predict the same fields $\mathbf H, \mathbf B$ in cavity.

Answer (score 1):

When an internal needle cavity is carved out we assume that the diameter of its cross section is vanishingly small compared to its length, hence the field of the poles at the end is negligible and is essentially equal to that of the component of the local field $H$ in the iron that is parallel with the axis because the tangential component of $H$ across different materials is continuous.

Comment: Yes but that is missing the point. H field of the poles on the cylinder faces is not negligible.

Comment: @hyportnex, I agree that in the case of Gilbert dipoles, the field inside the needle cavity would be the same field as if the cavity did not exist.

I disagree that the original field is negligible at the center.

Even if it was, we could raise M which results in more magnetic surface charge creating a magnetic field which is not negligible.

Comment: I was talking about the induced poles being negligible at the ends of the cavity surface and thought that you referred to the same in your post "...because it's approximately the field between two distant point charges, But those point charges are opposite in sign, etc." In fact, the field induced by the end poles of a long thin magnetized rod has nearly zero $H$ in its middle because of the demagnetizing effect of the poles, see https://archive.org/details/arnold-sommerfeld-auth.-electrodynamics.-lectures-on-theoretical-physics-vol.-3-academic-press-1952/page/81/mode/2up